# Visual Studio 2013 - c++ code map error message

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, code-map

I've used Visual Studio's 'Code Maps' extensively for my C# projects in the past. I'm now working on a native c++ project and running into problems. When I add a class or method to a Code Map I get the following error message with no context or help available. Any ideas what the cause is?

```
    Error Fail to get symbol's namespace
```

I should not that the project compiles and runs without a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was my mistake and not a bug. I had incorrectly put includes in my headers such that almost all .cpp files included all .h files even if they weren't needed. It appears this caused the codemap application to crash. I went through and correctly included only the required .h files and correctly created my precompiled headers. This makes the codemap run as it should.

Answer (score 0):

[This MSDN page on Code Maps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj739835.aspx) notes under **Requirements** that C++ has limited support.

Comment: Do you know what these requirements are? I haven't found any more documentation other than use update 3.